# cron clock problem

Tags: linux, rhel5, cron, date

I have noticed on my RHEL 5.5 that cron daily starts an hour later (at 1AM instead of midnight). System and hardware clock are the same. How can i set it so it will start at midnight?

**date**

```
[root@a ~]# date
Wed Mar  9 12:44:35 EST 2011
```

**hwclock**

```
[root@a ~]# /sbin/hwclock -r
Wed 09 Mar 2011 12:44:42 PM EST  -0.000484 seconds
```

**crontab**

```
0 0 * * *    /usr/sbin/ntpdate pool.ntp.org >/dev/null 2>&1
```

**cron log**

```
Mar  7 01:00:01 host crond[30420]: (root) CMD (/usr/sbin/ntpdate pool.ntp.org >/dev/null 2>&1)
```

**clock**

```
[root@a ~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/clock
ZONE="America/New York"
UTC=true
ARC=false
```

Comment: You should run the `ntpd` daemon instead of using `ntpdate`.

Comment: What are the contents of /etc/sysconfig/clock ?

Comment: I have edited the question with the additional info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you changed the system timezone setting?  If so, did you restart the crond service afterwards?

Regardless, I would restart the cron deamon, to make sure it's using the correct timezone.

```
# /sbin/service crond restart
```

Comment: Nothing has been changed after last server restart. So the given info was the same before. And I've also tried that.

Comment: hum... apparently there have been some changes made by my coworker. After server restart it seems to work now. Only crond restart was not enough.

Answer (score 1):

It is not always "enough" to restart crond.

1. set `/etc/localtime` as symlink to link with one of `/usr/share/zoneinfo/...` time zone file
2. set `/etc/sysconfig/clock` to `ZONE="CONTINENT/TOWN"` (+ UTC=true and ARC=false)
3. restart the whole machine

Answer (score 0):

IHMO, there's nothing wrong with daily cron jobs running at 1:00 am, as long as they run daily.

Check your `/etc/crontab` file, mine (RHEL 5.4) runs at 2:00 am by default:

```
# run-parts
01 * * * * root run-parts /etc/cron.hourly
02 4 * * * root run-parts /etc/cron.daily
22 4 * * 0 root run-parts /etc/cron.weekly
42 4 1 * * root run-parts /etc/cron.monthly
```

Look for your the cron.daily line. Edit to suit, e.g.:

```
01 0 * * * root run-parts /etc/cron.daily
```

Comment: It is for custom cron jobs. 0 0 * * * /scrip.php executes at 1 AM instead of Midnight.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about things running out of /etc/cron.daily, those are defined in /etc/crontab.  Make sure the entry for /etc/cron.daily is set to run at midnight, by default it runs at 04:02.

Comment: Default on some systems, maybe. Others may be different.